# Is there a "primitive-recursively enumerable" set whose complement is not such?

Tags: computability-theory, reference-request

Call a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ *primitive-recursively enumerable (p-r.e.)* if it is empty or an image of a primitive recursive function. I feel like a lot must be known about the poset of such sets ordered by inclusion, but I am unable to dig up references. Concretely, I would like to know whether there exists a p-r.e. set whose complement is not p-r.e.

The answer is affirmative if there is a complete set (in the sense of many-to-one reducibilities) that is enumerated by a primitive recursive function. My hunch is that such a set exists, but cannot come up with one.

Comment: Why does it say "2 Answers" when there are three answers posted? I see answers by Chad Groft, Antonio Porreca and myself. 

Comment: Is it because the answers were very nearly simultaneous? (As well as nearly identical, since we all hit upon the same argument!)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I realized the same thing over dinner. Now how do I accept all of them? Or do I accept just the first one.

Comment: I think it is fine to just accept the first one. And now I see that MO agrees that there are three answers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a stronger result: *Every r.e. set is primitive r.e. in your sense.*

Short proof: Kleene's Normal Form Theorem.

Longer proof:  Let *S* be an r.e. set, assumed WLOG nonempty; fix *a* ∈ *S*, and fix an algorithm *e* where *S* is precisely the range of the function computed by *e*.

Consider the following algorithm:  Given the input pair (*n*, *M*), run *e* on input *n* for *M* steps.  If it gives an output by then, output whatever *e* outputs; otherwise output *a*.

The functions which set up the initial state of computation, advance a state by one step, and extract the output from a final state, are all p.r.  Thus the above algorithm defines a p.r. function, and it is easy to check that its range is *S*.

Edit: Cutland's *Computability* is a decent resource for these questions.

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting question. From B. Rosser, [Extensions of some theorems of Gödel and Church](http://www.jstor.org/sici?sici=0022-4812%28193609%291%3A3%3C87%3AEOSTOG%3E2%2E0%2ECO%3B2-7):

> Corollary I. *If a class can be enumerated (allowing repetitions) by a general recursive function, it can be enumerated (allowing repetitions) by a primitive recursive function.*

Hence any complete recursively enumerable set (such as *K*) should work.

Answer (score 8):

I claim that a set is primitive recursive enumerable if and only if it is computably enumerable. So the answer to your question is affirmative.

Clearly any p-r.e. set is c.e., since primitive recursive functions are computable. Conversely, suppose that A is computably enumerable. We want to show A is p-r.e. If A is empty, then we're done. So fix some element a<sub>0</sub> in A. Since A is c.e., it is the domain of a computable function f, computed by program e. Consider now the function h(s,n) = n, if s codes the proof of a halting computation of program e on input n, and otherwise h(s,n) = a<sub>0</sub>. The function h is defined by Δ<sub>0</sub> cases, and hence is primitive recursive. Also, the range of h is A, as desired.

So there are numerous sets A as you desire!